# Выбор технологии для будущей работы

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, .net, работа

Имеется несколько лет опыта с платформой .NET (в основном проекты WinForms на C#). Сейчас хочу перейти на другую технологию этой же платформы (по причине устаревания WinForms и сокращения кол-ва проектов под неё), но не могу определиться с выбором: WPF или ASP.NET. Попробовал их и обе довольно интересны, но не могу понять, что ближе по душе. Понятно, что разница очевидна - программирование веб-проектов или десктопных, но я в сомнениях.
А на ваш взгляд, что более интересно и перспективно?

1. WPF
2. ASP.NET WebForms
3. ASP.NET MVC

Ответ прошу прокомментировать.
Заранее благодарен за ответ!

Comment: Ну еще немного и пересядете под Java - паттерн движения правильный: Winforms->WPF->ASP->JSP->Java :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сам я программирую под WPF. Технология интересная, но требует много знания различных моментов, очень долго учить. Если бы у меня был шанс сделать свой выбор раньше (а раньше с интернетом у меня были проблемы), то я все же выбрал [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) MVC или Java. Хотя WPF тоже ничего, только вакансий на него не так много - следовательно не так востребован. Но с WPF можно легко пересесть на Silverlight, а лучше если понравился XAML, сразу начинать с него. С другой стороны если начать с [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) то можно заодно поднять и HTML, CSS, JavaScript jQuery. Так что выбор очевиден - [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) или (и) CMS какой-нибудь.
Вот я как себе это представляю (сугубо мое видение:) )

1. [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) MVC -> HTML (CSS) -> SQL -> (jQuery) -> CMS -> Silverlight -> (WPF) - уровень
2. PHP (MySQL) -> CMS -> jQuery (AJAX) - (просто и) интересно
3. WPF -> Silverlight -> [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) - эксклюзивно (my)
4. Objective-C - перспективно
5. C++ -> ASM32 -> DisASM -> HACK 0101001010 - не советую хД
6. C++ -> Qt - серьезный С++
7. C++ -> Android SDK - скучно не будет
8. Java -> JavaFX - очень хорошая технология
9. Flash - без комментариев
10. Unity3D - советую любителям игр

Может что забыл напомните, дополню (и исправлю если что). Жду комментов

Comment: Благодарю, очень интересно написали. Я тоже вклоняюсь к ASP.NET всё больше и больше...

Comment: @Jembo_by По-моему, вместо того, чтобы склоняться, полезнее брать и пробовать :)

Comment: @Jembo_by Мне кажется, что и другие технологии заслуживают своего внимания

Comment: @semenvx27 попробовал уже немало технологий и сред разработки, но вернулся всё равно на .NET:)

Answer (score 6):

ИМХО более перспективно web. Я бы выбрал [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) MVC. Причины очень просты. В последнее время намечена тенденция перемещения данных в облака, открывается множество сервисов, которые предоставляются посредством веб. Рынок настольных приложений, конечно, всё также популярен, но наибольшим спросом сейчас пользуются именно веб- и мобильные технологии.

Comment: А вы, ради интереса, в какой области работаете?

Comment: Пока ни в какой. Я стою на пороге, как войти. Но выбрал ASP.NET MVC. Хотя сейчас есть свой проектик, его я делаю на WPF, но по той причине, что такой вещи нет на Desktop-ах.

Answer (score 5):

Еще один голос за веб. Мой совет: [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) MVС. И действительно - облачные сервисы сейчас популярнее коробочных версий. Их проще поддерживать и пользователю ничего не нужно устанавливать для того, чтобы пользоваться продуктом. Открыл браузер и вуаля)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.